# Faster way to rotate an image with 90 degree or multiples

Tags: java, image, image-processing, parallel-processing, rotation

I want to read an image from an folder and write it back rotated.
Which is the **faster** way (not the easier one) to rotate an image with 90 degree or multiples of **90 degreee (90, 180, 270)** and just it in Java 8?

I've search on internet a lot of time to find the answer of this question... but nothing. So I'm thinking of you guys, maybe one of you coud help me with this. I would be really recognize of that person.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Have you heard of an Affine Transform?

Comment: Yes I've heard about this and I've already make some tests with it. But I'm not sure if it's the faster way or not...

Comment: The calculation of that rotation is not even 0.001% of the time needed for I/O and possibly compression. (There is actually not really a calculation. You just got a different visiting behaviour of pixel-indices constrained to these *nice* rotation candidates: 90 ° switch rows and columns; 180 ° loop in reversed-mode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @sascha: "*You just got a different visiting behaviour of pixel-indices constrained to these nice rotation candidates".*

So you can use an image processing framework for accessing the pixels and transforming the image in such a way.

In my case I used [Marvin Framework](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net). On my notebook the rotation process of a 500x298 image took 12 milliseconds.

**auto.jpg:**
[image]

**auto_90.jpg:**
[image]

**auto_180.jpg:**
[image]

**auto_270.jpg:**
[image]

**Source code:**

```
public class RotateImages {

    public RotateImages(){
        MarvinImage image = MarvinImageIO.loadImage("./res/auto.jpg");
        MarvinImageIO.saveImage(rotate90(image), "./res/auto_90.jpg");
        MarvinImageIO.saveImage(rotate180(image), "./res/auto_180.jpg");
        MarvinImageIO.saveImage(rotate270(image), "./res/auto_270.jpg");
    }

    private MarvinImage rotate90(MarvinImage image){
        MarvinImage imageOut = new MarvinImage(image.getHeight(), image.getWidth());
        for(int y=0; y<image.getHeight(); y++){
            for(int x=0; x<image.getWidth(); x++){
                int newX = y;
                int newY = (image.getWidth()-1)-x;
                imageOut.setIntColor(newX, newY, image.getIntColor(x, y));
            }
        }
        return imageOut;
    }

    private MarvinImage rotate180(MarvinImage image){
        MarvinImage imageOut = new MarvinImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
        for(int y=0; y<image.getHeight(); y++){
            for(int x=0; x<image.getWidth(); x++){
                int newX = (image.getWidth()-1)-x;
                int newY = (image.getHeight()-1)-y;
                imageOut.setIntColor(newX, newY, image.getIntColor(x, y));
            }
        }
        return imageOut;
    }

    private MarvinImage rotate270(MarvinImage image){
        MarvinImage imageOut = new MarvinImage(image.getHeight(), image.getWidth());
        for(int y=0; y<image.getHeight(); y++){
            for(int x=0; x<image.getWidth(); x++){
                int newX = (image.getHeight()-1)-y;
                int newY = x;
                imageOut.setIntColor(newX, newY, image.getIntColor(x, y));
            }
        }
        return imageOut;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    new RotateImages(); }
}
```

Comment: For those who want to rotate 90 degrees to the right, instead of to the left as done here use this code for the newX and newY: `int newX = (image.getHeight() - 1) - y;
                     int newY = x;`